# Как закрыть Активити?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.harrix.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.harrix.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;



public class haqqimiz  extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageView haqiimizimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.haqqimiz);
        // toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




              picasso  .load("https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10686674_1579500448958894_5264196578205990291_n.jpg?oh=a33cdf0109f2032f19049d594f70b47f&oe=58203FFB")
                .into(haqiimizimage);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
}
```

Как закрыть 2 Активити и попасть на MainAcitvity c помощью Toolbar у меня не получилось

Comment: можете например запустить MainAcitvity с очисткой бекстека.

Comment: все я уже сделал

Comment: просто поставил финиш)так сказать убил активность

Comment: @elik если нашли ответ - напишите его здесь, возможно это поможет другим в будущем

Answer (score 1):

Код рабочий в нем проблем нет проблема в эмуляторе была))))
если кому надо берите

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class );
SecondActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Переключается на MainActivity и вызывает метод onDestroy() у SecondActivity.

Comment: Зачем тебе намерение?нет смысла ты даешь ему обезательность перехода ,сработает для 1го для 2х и для 15,а что если проект на 40-45 клас фрагментов?некорректный метод уничтожать через намерение

Comment: Не понял ваш комментарий: некорректный метод уничтожать через намерение

Comment: Ты через интент даешь явное намерение оно есть нехорошо понимаешь?суть жизненного цикла накладываеться таблицей один на другого а ты закрываешь конечный активити минуя все до этого ,фактически у тебя активити есть в  памяти , или короче говоря есть 10 страниц ты с первого перешел на 10 но закрыв 10 открыл другие 9

Comment: оба используем посути  Смерть активити но твой это не смерть а больше переход с закрытием

Comment: А! Всмысле, что я интентом сотру backStackActivity? Ну это да. Вопрос, ведь был не "как вернутся в MainAcitvity", а "попасть на MainAcitvity". Вот с помощью интента можно попасть, а то что сотрётся бэкстэк - я не думал что это имеет для вас значение.

Comment: ))но за ответ спасибо!